# custom android sdk build

Tags: android, sdk

I would like to add custom android OS, and followed these steps to create the SDK:

```
. build/envsetup.sh 
lunch sdk-eng 
make -j(thread num) update-api 
make -j(thread num) sdk
```

The SDK is located under /out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk/

Is there any possibility to say what should be inside this sdk and what not? If I would like to add some library to be part of SDK, do I have to add it somewhere(include it in some file)?

Thank you